# how to hang handlers on vaading-grid row / cell using litElement?

Tags: vaadin, lit-element

I need to track clicks on a row and determine the current one, as well as clicks on a cell, how can I do this in conjunction with litElement?

```
       <vaadin-grid .items ="${test_data}" theme="special-field">
          <vaadin-grid-column  path="company" header="Company"></vaadin-grid-column>
          <vaadin-grid-column  path="script" header="Script"></vaadin-grid-column>
          <vaadin-grid-column  path="stage" header="Stage"></vaadin-grid-column>
          <vaadin-grid-column  path="atributes" header="Atributes"></vaadin-grid-column>
        </vaadin-grid>


   test(event){
        console.log(event.target)
    }
```

I found this solution for row changes but maybe there is more correct way and how listen changes of cell

```
  firstUpdated() {
        const grid = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('vaadin-grid');
        grid.addEventListener('active-item-changed', (event) => this.test2(event, grid));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<vaadin-grid>` has the event already. You just have to listen for it.

Add to `<vaadin-grid...>` an event listener for `active-item-changed`, like

```
<vaadin-grid
   id="grid"
   @active-item-changed=${this._activeItemChanged}...
```

Then write your method:

```
_activeItemChanged(evt) {
  const grid = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('grid');
  const item = evt.detail.value;
  grid.selectedItems = item ? [item] : [];
  // Set info string.
  if (item) {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('record-selected', {
        detail: item,
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true,
      }),
    );
  } else {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('record-unselected', {
        detail: '',
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true,
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

For more info, see https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid